# Replacing a varying number of rows within a group in data frame

Tags: r, replace, group-by

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1, 7), rep(2, 12), rep(3, 9)), val = runif(28), num_adjustments = c(rep(5, 7), rep(4, 12), rep(2, 9)), adj = c(rep(0.5,28)))

df$val_adj <- df$val
```

My goal is to replace `val_adj`such that it is equal to `df$val+df$adj` only when the row number is less than or equal to `num_adjustments` per `id`.

So, for `id == 1`, I'd like to do it for the first 5 rows, for `id == 2`, I want this for the first 4 rows etc.

So far, I've tried:

```
df$val_adj <- with(df, ave(val_adj, id, FUN = function(i) replace(i, seq_along(i) <= num_adjustments,val+adj)))
```

However, that seems to evaluate `num_adjustments` to whatever the first row of that column is (`5` in my case) and then repeats whatever the first 5 values for `id == 1` to all other `id`s.

I'd appreciate any advice on this matter. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `id` and add `val + adj` when current `row_number()` is less than equal to `num_adjustments` value for each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(val_adj = ifelse(row_number() <= num_adjustments, val + adj, val))

#      id     val num_adjustments   adj val_adj
#    <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1 0.114                 5   0.5 0.614  
# 2     1 0.622                 5   0.5 1.12   
# 3     1 0.609                 5   0.5 1.11   
# 4     1 0.623                 5   0.5 1.12   
# 5     1 0.861                 5   0.5 1.36   
# 6     1 0.640                 5   0.5 0.640  
# 7     1 0.00950               5   0.5 0.00950
# 8     2 0.233                 4   0.5 0.733  
# 9     2 0.666                 4   0.5 1.17   
#10     2 0.514                 4   0.5 1.01   
# … with 18 more rows
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1, 7), rep(2, 12), rep(3, 9)), val = runif(28), 
      num_adjustments = c(rep(5, 7), rep(4, 12), rep(2, 9)), adj = c(rep(0.5,28)))
df$val_adj <- df$val
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ave()` to get a logical vector `x` indicating where the row number of `id` doesn't exceed `num_adjustments`. `x` can then also be used on the LHS.

```
df$val_adj[x] <- 
  with(df, val + adj)[x <- with(df, ave(val_adj, id, FUN=seq_along)) <= df$num_adjustments]

head(df, 10)
#    id adj num_adjustments          val     val_adj
# 1   1 0.5               1  0.005771755  0.50577176
# 2   1 0.5               1 -0.350911424 -0.35091142
# 3   1 0.5               1 -1.736723720 -1.73672372
# 4   1 0.5               1  0.046552388  0.04655239
# 5   1 0.5               1 -1.121484596 -1.12148460
# 6   2 0.5               1 -0.781560056 -0.28156006
# 7   2 0.5               1  0.849904248  0.84990425
# 8   3 0.5               2  1.763790903  2.26379090
# 9   3 0.5               2  0.845641647  1.34564165
# 10  3 0.5               2 -0.544836427 -0.54483643
```

Seems to be faster than the `dplyr` solution.

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
# dplyr 45.41649 46.09873 47.46352 46.78096 48.48704 50.19312     3   a
#   ave 31.86809 34.95828 38.30649 38.04847 41.52569 45.00292     3   a
```

#### Benchmark data

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e3
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:n, function(i) 
  data.frame(id=i, adj=0.5, num_adjustments=rep(sample(1:(i-1), 1), sample(i:9, 1)))))
df <- transform(df, val=rnorm(nrow(df2)))
df$val_adj <- df$val
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, val_adj := val]
i1<- df[, .I[seq_len(.N) <= num_adjustments], id]$V1
df[i1, val_adj := val + adj]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1, 7), rep(2, 12), rep(3, 9)), val = runif(28), 
      num_adjustments = c(rep(5, 7), rep(4, 12), rep(2, 9)), adj = c(rep(0.5,28)))
df$val_adj <- df$val
```